# Jquery datatable returning 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "link.json",
      "dataSrc": "passwords"
    }
  });
});
```

However, when the table tries to load, it returns an `alert` with the following message:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I have read the documentation, but still can't find what is wrong.

Comment: Is the AJAX request to `link.json` being made, and is it returning any data? You can check this in the network tab of dev tools

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it seems that request is made, but it does not bring any response. It shows that request is not finished.

Comment: That sounds like the cause then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when ever you are using server side datatable you have to pass the detail of your columns as well . You have to give column details as below also you can use the below code for datatable.You have to give the column detail in same order you have given in your table heading .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
     "sAjaxSource": "link.json",  // Your url
                   "bServerSide": true,  
                   "bSearchable": true,  
                   "order": [[1, 'asc']],  
                   "columns": [  // You can mention here all your columns you want to display
                       {  
                           "data": "Name",   // Should be your json object property
                       },
                       {  
                           "data": "City",  
                       }
                   ]  
  });
});
```

Hope it helps !!!